# Para instalar un software creado por mi debo instalar una BD

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, aplicación-escritorio

ante todo muchas gracias por leer.

Soy un **novato** de verdad, estoy interesado en hacer un software, con C#, un aplicacion windows la cual trabaja con su propia base de datos.
Para desarrollarlo estoy utilizando SQL Server 2014, mi duda es una vez que termine el proyecto y lo quiera vender. Como funciona todo ese mundo?, es decir
**cuando quiera instalarle al cliente mi software debere instalarle Sql Server, o como es?**. O se guarda en una especie de base de datos del programa, sinceramente soy muy noob y me gustaria saber como es ese tema.

Por que por lo que pesa Sql Server 2014, no me imagino instalandoselo a un cliente, y ya de paso, **cuando instalas un programa de gestion o demas que te descargas desde la web, ninguno te pide Sql Server o algun gestor de base de datos y eso es lo que me desconcerta muchisimo.**

***Muchas gracias***

Comment: La BD irá en servidor y necesitarás un Web Service para mediar entre BD y App. Supongo que habrá otras vías más sencillas de implementar pero no sé si son adecuadas. Espera a ver si alguno propone algo más.

Comment: Para aplicaciones que necesitan una base de datos sencilla que no requiera instalación en el cliente, es mejor usar algo como Sqlite, que almacena la base de datos en un archivo por lo que no requiere ningun tipo de instalación adicional

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa también es que algunas aplicaciones de hecho sí instalan una versión de sql express en la máquina que no pesa tanto, el tema es que como dice Pikoh dependiendo de tu aplicación puedes irte por un gestor de BD como el mencionado ya que a diferencia de AsieR_2 no siempre el esquema es así, depende de qué quieras hacer, si tu aplicación es standallone (la va a tener tu usuario en su máquina nada más) entonces no necesariamente se deba conectar a un servidor.. Te pongo el ejemplo de SAINT contable que tiene su BD local. Saludos!

Comment: te recomiendo que investigues versiones compactas o transportables,
como Sqlite el cual es un formato de archivo que funciona como base de datos. tambien esta la version compacta de SQl, pero tiene algunas limitaciones, en definitiva no quieres irte por la ruta de instalar sql server en la computadora del cliente.

Comment: CUando ofreces tu software, defines unos requerimientos funcionales y otros no funcionales. Los funcionales son lo que hace tu software, los no funcionales son del contexto del mismo. En los no funcionales se define que tu software requiere X o Y software base, como la base de datos. El cliente cumple con instalarla (o decide no usar tu software por costos de las licencias, etc)

Comment: Depende mucho del enfoque que le vas a dar a tu sistema. Pues este puede ser utilizado por una empresa que quizás tenga un servidor en el cuál puedas montar la bd como menciona Asier. Pero si lo que buscas es algo que funcione de manera local (una bd independiente por máquina) agregas la bd al proyecto y al hacer la publicación del mismo especificas que quieres utilizar sqlServerLocalDB, tomemos en cuenta que también tiene sus limitaciones. Define el tipo de proyecto que quieres desarrollar y a partir de ahí toma sugerencias. :D éxitos!